# Как findContours() сохраняет найденные точки контура

Tags: c++, opencv

Есть изображение круглого предмета, для которого надо найти его геометрический центр. 
Снятые, с помощью findContours(), с него контуры выглядят так(один из вариантов):
[image: картинка с контурами]

Так как контуры всегда "рваные", то найти контур полного круга и снять с него минимумы/максимумы для поиска центра не представляется возможным.
Для поиска геом.центра я беру самый длинный контур, на нём выбираю три точки на расстоянии друг от друга и по формуле декартовых координат центра уже, собственно, ищу его([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Описанная_окружность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)). Но когда я рисую на изображении контур, который я рассматриваю, и точки на нём, то оказывается что точки расположены не там где я ожидаю их увидеть. Для точек я выбираю первую, после четверти контура и после половины, но располагаются они на других расстояниях друг от друга.

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
findContours(centerROI, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, 
CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

int maxPerimIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    if(contours[i].size() > contours[maxPerimIndex].size())
        maxPerimIndex = i;
}
// точки для определения центра
Point p1 = contours[maxPerimIndex][0];
Point p2 = contours[maxPerimIndex][contours[maxPerimIndex].size() / 4];
Point p3 = contours[maxPerimIndex][contours[maxPerimIndex].size() / 2];


///////////////////////////////
// тут поиск центра
///////////////////////////////

Mat tmp = Mat::zeros(centerROI.size(), centerROI.type());
    drawContours( tmp, contours, maxPerimIndex, Scalar( 255, 255, 
    255), 1, 8);
circle( tmp, Point(CX, CY), 1, Scalar( 255, 255, 255), -1, 8, 0 );
circle( tmp, p1, 3, Scalar( 255, 255, 255), -1, 8, 0 );
circle( tmp, p2, 3, Scalar( 255, 255, 255), -1, 8, 0 );
circle( tmp, p3, 3, Scalar( 255, 255, 255), -1, 8, 0 );
```

Итоговое фото выглядит так:
[image: Итоговое фото]

Причём, если выбрать в контуре первую точку, последнюю и середину, вообще какой-то бред получается:

```
p1 = contours1[maxPerimIndex][0];
p2 = contours1[maxPerimIndex][contours1[maxPerimIndex].size() / 2];
p3 = contours1[maxPerimIndex][contours1[maxPerimIndex].size() - 1];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верхняя точка,которую вы видите - это p3 практически наложившаяся на p1(между ними разница в пару пикселей).
Получается, что в контуре точки хранятся в каком-то непонятном для меня порядке и я не могу нормально их выбрать для нахождения центра.

Помогите понять как хранятся точки и можно ли их сортировать так, чтобы в векторе контура они шли "по порядку" или способ как можно выбрать точки на равноудалённом друг от друга расстоянии.

В findContours() я использовал такие методы нахождения контуров: 
CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS, CV_LINK_RUNS.
CV_CHAIN_CODE выдавал какую-то дичь в ввиде прямых, остальные методы располагают точки примерно в одном интервале друг от друга.

Благодарю за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел, какие точки входят в контур при использовании последней картинки как исходника. Получается, что алгоритм находит самую верхнюю точку контура (не конец линии), затем идет по внешней стороне против часовой стрелки до правого нижнего конца, заворачивается внутрь, проходит по часовой стрелке по внутренней стороне всю кривую, заворачивается наружу и против часовой  стрелки доходит до начальной верхней точки.

Получается, что можно поступить так - взять первую точку - это верхняя. Затем идти по списку, пока не найдем первый (устойчивый) максимум по Y. И третьей точкой взять средний между ними индекс. Этот подход, похоже, будет работать и для небольшой дуги концами вверх или вниз.

---

Если не вдаваться в систему хранения, то можно попробовать следующее - выбрать три случайных несовпадающих точки  контура так, чтобы площадь треугольника на этих точках была побольше - сгенерировать несколько случайных троек и выбрать ту, для которой векторное произведение `ABxAC` побольше

Comment: Это моя ошибка при копировании кода сюда - я его переделывал при создании вопроса чтобы код читабельным был. У меня maxPerimIndex == i. Поправил.

Comment: Тогда отредактируйте вопрос, приведя реальный кусок кода, чтобы не было сомнений.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, я её опробую. Но всё таки хотелось бы понять как оно внутри хранится. Создаётся впечатление что где-то до половины вектора идёт контур,   а потом он разворачивается и идёт обратно т.е. контур как бы двойной получается. Скажите, а эти точки можно как-нибудь отсортировать? В вашем предложении минус заключается в том, что неизвестно сколько времени рандом займёт прежде чем попадётся подходящий  треугольник.

Comment: Благодарю за информацию - она помогла мне модифицировать поиск точек. Хотелось только отметить, что ваш вариант поиска точек  корректен. К примеру, если левая граница контура находится всего в нескольких пикселях от самой верхней точки, то вторая и третья, опять же будут рядом. Сейчас у меня так: 1-я точка - самая верхняя, вторая - самая нижняя, а третья посередине между первой и второй, НО индекс первой точки перезаписывается(на свой "внутренний" индекс) если вторая точка найдена в правой части контура. Так я избавляюсь от близкого расположения точек. Далеко не идеально, но в целом работает.